# Chrome extension wants host_permissions to be defined, but they are

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm developing a Chrome extension using manifest V3, and I want to be able to set an HTTP proxy in the browser and be able to provide the username and password for it.

The error I'm getting is `Unchecked runtime.lastError: You need to request host permissions in the manifest file in order to be notified about requests from the webRequest API.`

### manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "Hello Extensions",
  "description": "Base Level Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "hello.html",
    "default_icon": "hello_extensions.png"
  },
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "notifications",
    "contextMenus",
    "history",
    "background",
    "proxy",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestAuthProvider"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

### background.js

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  var config = {
    mode: "fixed_servers",
    rules: {
      singleProxy: {
        scheme: "http",
        host: "41.139.238.6:1019",
        port: 8080
      },
      bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
    }
  };

  chrome.proxy.settings.set(
      {value: config, scope: 'regular'},
      function() {}
  );
});


chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(function(details, callbackFn) {
    callbackFn({
        authCredentials: { 
           username: "my_username", 
           password: "my_password" 
        }
    });
  }, 
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, 
  ['asyncBlocking']
);
```

As you can see, my `host_permissions` are already defined in the manifest, so I'm not sure why Chrome keeps complaining.

## Full code

https://github.com/Thoufak/Extension-test

Comment: It means 1) you didn't reload the extension in chrome://extensions UI after editing, or 2) you're looking at an old error in chrome://extensions UI which you can remove by clicking the trashcan icon.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I've just tried restarting Chrome, and it didn't help. Also, I updated my question and included the full extension source code.

Comment: Restarting Chrome won't help. You need to reload the extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm, thanks. The problem was the old error log which you mentioned. It's extremely unintuitive that it doesn't get cleared when you reload the extension. You can post an answer to this question, and I will accept it.